# How to get the length of an jagged array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to get the total no of items in my list which is updated from a SQLAlchemy command, it is a jagged array something like this..

```
list = [['linux'], ['ML'], ['linux', 'ML', 'Data Science', 'GIT'],['linux', 'Data Science', 'GIT'], ['GIT'], ['ML', 'GIT'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['Data Science']]
length = len(list)
```

I get the output as: 10

How do I get the length as: 16 ? that is total no of items in the list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `list`, there's a builtin with that name already. I'll assume you meant "lst".

If your lists are small, use

```
>>> len(sum(lst, []))
16
```

Not recommended for large lists because list concatenation with `sum` is quadratic in time. However, this is really concise, so reconsider for small inputs.

If your lists are large (or have many elements), use

```
>>> sum(len(l) for l in lst)
16
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. And i used "list" just to illustrate my problem, actual name of my list is "answers". anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Using sum and a generator expression:

```
lst = [['linux'], ['ML'], ['linux', 'ML', 'Data Science', 'GIT'],['linux', 'Data Science', 'GIT'], ['GIT'], ['ML', 'GIT'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['Data Science']]
num_items = sum(len(l) for l in lst)

print(num_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

`totalLen = 0
for inner in list:
 totalLen = totalLen + len(inner)`

If you want to drill down to more than one level I'd suggest you write a recursive function that does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Consider flattening the list first if you intend to use `len()`:

```
>>> my_list = [['linux'], ['ML'], ['linux', 'ML', 'Data Science', 'GIT'],['linux', 'Data Science', 'GIT'], ['GIT'], ['ML', 'GIT'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['Data Science']]
>>> len([item for sublist in my_list for item in sublist])
16
```

Comment: I would recommend against flattening the list to compute its length, it is more efficient to compute the length for each sublist and add them up.

Comment: The author's use case is for a list with 16 elements. I'm not sure he cares much about efficiency at this point, so I gave him an answer that enables him to use `len()` as he is used to.

Answer (score 0):

My code iterates through the nested lists, and gets the `len` of each of the nested lists inside the list. Then, I just sum 'store' and provide the required output. This is my code:

```
list_1 = [['linux'], ['ML'], ['linux', 'ML', 'Data Science', 'GIT'],['linux', 'Data Science', 'GIT'], ['GIT'], ['ML', 'GIT'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['linux'], ['Data Science']]
store = [len(x) for x in list_1]
print(sum(store))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really "jagged" or completely randomly nested list, you can use a recursive function something like below:

```
>>> a = [1, [1, 3, 4], [[0, 5], 2, 3]]
>>> len_rec = lambda l: sum(len_rec(i) for i in l) if isinstance(l,list) else 1
>>> len_rec(a)
8
```